# How can i set a delay for voice recognition?

Tags: android

I have this code here :

```
          Text-To-Speech("Hello");

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Actions to do after 10 seconds
            }
        }, 10000);

        VOICE_RECOGNITION();
```

This is not working, after saying, "Hello", and if i say hello, the voice recognition hears "hello hello". How can i make a delay so after 4 seconds VOICE_RECOGNITION() starts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what you need to do is this:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
} catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
```

This will sleep your current thread for 4000 ms (which is 4 seconds). Just keep in mind that using `Thread.sleep(xxx)` is usually a bad practice, as it's unreliable and produces flaky code and results. I imagine you assume that `Text-to-speech("Hello")` will finish in 4 seconds, that's why you want this delay. Imagine however that in the future you change the text ... or perhaps read it in other language, where the work/phraze is super long - then your code will fail.

Instead of using a manual delay of 4/6/whatever-seconds, I'd rather use an interface. I'd create an interface with a method `void onTextToSpeechFinished()`, which will be called after that's finished. Much cleaner and stable solution.